# ASP.NET DLL folder change

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I am using this method to change the DLL folder. However, this method does not allow access to the parent directory.

I would be happy if you help. Thank you.

Web.config file:

```
</configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin;C:\Windows\SysWOW64" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the files separately. Thank you.

Solution:

Web.config

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <codeBase version="5.2.3.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Web.Mvc.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <codeBase version="5.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Web.Http.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <codeBase version="5.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <codeBase version="5.2.3.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <codeBase version="4.5.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Design"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <codeBase version="4.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Design.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <codeBase version="4.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Windows.Forms.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Entity"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <codeBase version="4.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Web.Entity.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Linq"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <codeBase version="4.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/bin2/subbin/System.Data.Linq.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```